# Boost python C4244 warning

Tags: python, c++, boost

So according to this link:
http://boost.2283326.n4.nabble.com/1-34-0-Python-Type-Conversion-Wanring-td2624877.html the warning generated in boost/python/caller.hpp:

```
C:\Boost\include\boost-1_60\boost/python/detail/caller.hpp(55): warning C4244: 
    'return': conversion from 'Py_ssize_t' to 'unsigned int', possible loss of data
```

should be resolved after version 1.34 of the boost library. But as you can see from the copied warning of my project I am using boost 1.6 and still get this warning. All that is changed is the line it occurs (52->55).

Is this issue not resolved for version 1.6?

Answer (score 1):

According to [svn.boost.org](https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/3353) it was not fixed until 1.57.0.

It tested it and it was also not fixed in 1.60.

Comment: Ok, the question is: Is this issue not resolved for version 1.6. The answer is: no it is not resolved. How does this not answer the question?